# Como rodar um projeto RestFull no servidor TomCat?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

Criei um simples projeto, e conseguir rodar ele no SpringTools, conseguir rodar ele também no servidor **Heroku** e agora estou tentando rodar ele no servidor TomCat no meu computador local.

eu coloquei o tomcat para rodar, e empacotei o projeto com o comando;

> MVN clean install

peguei o projeto que está com .war e coloquei na pasta webapp no caminho;

> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps

Quando fui testar no postman não rodou , dá erro 404, o que será que pode ter acontecido?

Quando coloquei o arquivo .war no projeto ele gerou uma pasta chamada **midia** como podem ver na figura abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele gerou uma pasta diferente daquela do projeto original como podem ver abaixo;

[Projeto](https://github.com/wladyband/tomcat)

tudo que preciso é conseguir rodar meu projeto no meu servidor local.

Estrutura do meu projeto;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

tem que adicionar esse artefato

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

e modifiquei disso

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MidiaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MidiaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

para isso;

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MidiaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MidiaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MidiaApplication.class);
    }
}
```